# Javascript fetch gif using POST and display

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, fetch-api

I was scouring through numerous other questions exactly asking the same. But couldnt get any of them to work in my case.

Basically what I need is to fetch a gif file from an API and display it. The image returned is a base64 encoded gif image built as shown below;

```
with io.BytesIO() as newfp:
    ....logic....
    buf = base64.b64encode(newfp.getvalue()).decode()
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Content-Type": 'image/gif',
        },
        "body": buf,
        "isBase64Encoded": True,
    }
```

What I have come up is as shown below based on this [link](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/fetching-images-with-the-fetch-api-fb8761ed27b2),

```js
fetch('https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/xxxx', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: ""
  }).then((response) => {
  response.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
    var base64Flag = 'data:image/gif;base64,';
    var imageStr = arrayBufferToBase64(buffer);
        var image = new Image();
    image.src = base64Flag + imageStr;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  });
});

function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    console.log(buffer);
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer));

  bytes.forEach((b) => binary += String.fromCharCode(b));

  return window.btoa(binary);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with the below code.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/xxxx");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = response;
xhr.send();

function response(e) {
  (this.response.text().then(imageStr => {
    var base64Flag = 'data:image/gif;base64,';
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = base64Flag + imageStr;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  }));
}
```